# mysql - THEORY help needed in designing a table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am constructing a document control table. In the simplest form the document has the following structure:

```
doc_id (Primary Key)
name
doc_type 
doc_category
```

There are two types of doc_types, link or blob. If it is a blob it will have its own set of doc_category and if it is a link it will have a different set of categories.

Eg

```
doc_type = blob, doc_category = [photo,certificate]
doc_type = link, doc_category = [procedure, certificate]
```

What is the best way to set-up the relationship table? To ensure blob is assigned the correct doc_category values, will this need to be done within the business/php logic or can I do this in mysql? If so how? Is there a better way to do this?

Finally, for workflow reasons both the blob and link need to have a common doc_id, hence separating them into a separate table with their own primary key will not work. Any advice on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, it would work if all the ids in one table were even and in the other table odd

Comment: Thanks for the comment but unfortunately that will not work as there likely be a third doc_type added.

Comment: So, - just a thought - perhaps  your PK should really be (doc_id,doc_type)?

Comment: Normalize your database design.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you want to make category tree.
So you need tables:

```
category_id (Primary key)
parent_id  (Relation to category_id if parent_id = 0 then this category the root)
category_name

doc_id (Primary key)
category_id (foreign key)
doc_name
doc_content
```

You need separate category tree from documents. To select categories you can use:

```
-- select categories
SELECT * FROM  categories WHERE parent_id = :category:
-- select documents
SELECT * FROM documents WHERE category_id = :category:
-- select documents with categories
SELECT * FROM documents d INNER JOIN categories c ON  d.category_id = category_id WHERE d.category_id = :category:
```

If you want to have documents with categories inside. You can use structure:

```
documents:
    document_id (Primary key)
    category_id (Relation to category_id if = 0 then this document is main)
    document_name
    document_content

categories:    
    category_id (Primary key)
    document_id (foreign key to main document)
    category_name
```

You can select document with categories:

```
SELECT * 
FROM documents main_doc 
   LEFT JOIN categories c ON main_doc.document_id = c.document_id
   LEFT JOIN documents doc_in_cat ON c.category_id = doc_in_cat.category_id
WHERE
  main_doc.doc_id = :document:
```

Comment: Liutas thank you so much, I was trying to figure out the cleanest way to do this and the category tree is exactly that. My initial thought was to have a separate relationship table for each category with corresponding doc id, but my fear was this relied on the php logic which could have introduced errors eg doc_id belonging to 2 category tablea. What you have suggested makes sense and will ensures the doc_id has one unique category, fantastic thanks again!